TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'css') JestJs test
I get this error trying to run test for my Jquery code
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'css')

      20 |
      21 | export const alertError = (message, errorclass) => {
    > 22 |   $(`.${errorclass}`).css("display", "block");
         |                      ^
      23 |   $(`.${errorclass}`).html(`
      24 |     <div class="alert alert-icon alert-error alert-bg alert-inline">
      25 |       <h4 class="alert-title">

      at alertError (static/js/utils/alert.js:22:22)
      at getUserChatrooms (static/js/modules/chat/chat_ajax.js:29:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (static/js/modules/chat/tests/chat_ajax.spec.js:38:45)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 5 passed, 6 total

My current mocks/jquery.js
import $ from 'jquery';

// Mock jQuery and attach it to the global object
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

// Turn off jQuery animations
jQuery.fx.off = true;

// Mock specific jQuery instances
$.fn.extend = jest.fn();
$.ajax = jest.fn();
$.fn = {
  on: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  children: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  attr: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  css: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  html: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
};

$.document = $();
$.document.body = $();

How do I fix this?  I can't think of a way to fix it without having to mock the alert.js functions.
